# how to redirect the user to the referer page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this part of my script

```
 <?php
     else:
 ?>
    <script>
        alert("You are not allowed to edit this CV!");
    </script>

 <?php
     echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1"; url="'.$the_class->settings[0]['DomainName'].'myresume.php"';
     endif;
 ?>
```

the objective is, after the alert box popped-out and the "ok" button was clicked,
the user should be redirected to http://www.mydomain.com/myresume.php

now the problem is, before the page loads the redirection, the alert box keeps popping out without reaching the destination page at all...how to fix this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this if you want to always send them back to http://www.mydomain.com/myresume.php:

```
<script>
   alert("You are not allowed to edit this CV!");
   window.location.href = 'http://www.mydomain.com/myresume.php';
</script>
```

You can do something like this if you instead want to send them back to whatever page they were on previously:

```
<script>
   alert("You are not allowed to edit this CV!");
   history.back();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem seems to be that you are trying to set a header after sending content.

You can try using the [`header` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php).  If that does not work, you can simply remove the `alert`.

If you need to display the `alert` you can put a `window.location` in the script tag and remove the php part.

You can also experiment by turning the output buffering off using [`ob_implicit_flush`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-implicit-flush.php).

Answer (score 0):

How about sending them back using javascript:

```
<?php
     else:
 ?>
    <script>
        alert("You are not allowed to edit this CV!");
        document.location = 
<?php
        echo '"'.$the_class->settings[0]['DomainName'].'myresume.php"';
?>
    ;
    </script>

 <?php
     endif;
 ?>
```